# Defining a condition in while loop causes overflow in Python, while in Matlab it wont

Tags: python, overflow

I've been working on an assignment for school. I like to start writing my code in Matlab if I start to have issues with using syntax in Python due to me being new to using Python. Currently, my code in Python is causing overflows and invalid values. I thus coded it in Matlab, but this seems to work in Matlab, so I'm pretty sure the way I'm calculating my condition for the while loop in Python is incorrect, but I can't seem to get it right.

Currently, the MRE I have that leads to this problem is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#evenwicht = reactie 2
#aA + bB -> cC -> dD + eE
#cC -> dD + eE
a = 1 ;b = 2 ;c = 3; d = 1; e = 2
t0 = 0
t_eind = 10
dt = 0.05
t = np.arange(t0, t_eind, dt)
n = len(t)
fout = 1
M = 1


Ca = np.zeros(n);
Cb = np.zeros(n); Cc = np.zeros(n);
Ca[0] = a; Cb[0] = b
Cc[0] = 0;

k1 = 1

def rA(Ca, Cb, Cc, t):
    -k1 * Ca**a * Cb**b
    return -k1 * Ca**a * Cb**b

while fout > 1e-3:
    t = np.arange(t0, t_eind, dt)
    n = len(t)
    for i in range(0,n-1):
        Ca[i+1] = Ca[i] + rA(Ca[i], Cb[i], Cc[i], t[i]) * dt
    fout = abs((M-Ca[n-1])/M)
    M = Ca[n-1]
    dt = dt/2
    

    
plt.plot(t,Ca);
plt.grid()
plt.autoscale()
plt.show()
```

Im quite sure it has to do with the lines `error = abs((M-Ca[-1])/M)` and `M = Ca[-1]` which I programmed in MatLab like this: `error = abs((M-Ca(end))/M)` and `M = Ca[end]`. I feel like the way I'm trying to splice the last calculated value in the array for `Ca` in my `for` loop is incorrect, but online all I could find is to either put `-1` within the splice or to call for the `len(Ca)` and to grab the last one by adding `-1` to the end of it.

The error code I receive is:

```
`<ipython-input-11-27cf4afbd18d>:20: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars
  -k1 * Ca**a * Cb**b * dt
<ipython-input-11-27cf4afbd18d>:20: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  -k1 * Ca**a * Cb**b * dt`
```

Which causes me to think that my while loop condition is never reached. I am **required** to use a `for` loop within a `while` loop.

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you want to do, and the code is not yet a working example (f.ex. Cb and Cc are not initialized)
But maybe you forgot to reset M=1 inside the loop?
And range(0,n-1) = [0, 1, ..., n-2]. I think you want to do range(0,n)

Comment: Hey Dwight, that is weird, I ran the code before posting and it ran giving me the error I posted, but now it seems to have broken. I'll edit the post once I figure out what happened. What I'm trying to achieve is to create a concentration profile of a certain reaction that's showed in the comments within the first lines of code.

Comment: I have edited the code, now, my `while`  loop condition is reached, but much earlier than it is in my MatLab code

Comment: Yes, because "while fout < 1e-3" is never gonna execute when fout is initialized to 1. I suspect you meant "while fout > 1e-3".

Comment: You are correct, I changed the condition quickly to see if I didn't make another mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.  Changing the condition to  `while fout > 1e-3` causes the overflow to happen again

Comment: What versions are you using? I get the logical out of bounds error in the second iteration of the loop (when there are twice as many values stored in Ca, Cb and Cc, but the length is still n.)
Also can you check the rA definition? Because the error states a different variation of that line.

Comment: I'm using the Python 3 kernel in JupyterLabs loaded from the Anaconda launcher. I checked my rA definition and using the given theory, it should be correct. Calculating the concentration values using the function defined in MatLab works just fine, as does by hand.

Comment: Calculating by hand gives me a [1, -3, -3, -3, ...] value for Ca, as does the code. You are not updating Cb and Cc. I don't know if that is intentionally or not, but that makes the Ca[i] + rA(Ca[i], Cb[i], Cc[i], t[i]) equal to 0  for every i different from 0.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an extra pair of eyes to look at this, I really appreciate it. I see that I forgot to add * dt to the end the calculation of Ca[i+1] = ...    I have edited this in the original post.. I am using Euler's method of generating a numeric input. After doing this I receive an index error `IndexError: index 200 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 200`

Comment: The * dt is what I meant before with "check the rA definition", because this was apperant in first your error. 
The out of bounds is what I mentioned before because you initialize Ca, .. as np.zeros(n), but since they should become longer every iteration, you should initialize them inside your while-loop.